# Service Fabric: supporting HTTP and HTTPS in a Kestrel-based stateless service

Tags: c#, stateless, kestrel

I have an existing stateless ASP.Net Core MVC service fabric service which by default (as code is generated by the wizard) uses HTTP. We need to also support HTTPS in the same service, using the same Controllers.

Two endpoints have been defined in the ServiceManifest.xml:

```
<Endpoints>
  <Endpoint Protocol="http" Name="HttpEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="16080" />
  <Endpoint Protocol="https" Name="HttpsEndpoint" Type="Input" Port="16443" />
</Endpoints>
```

Here's the GetServiceInstanceListeners override from the StatelessService derived class:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "HttpEndpoint", url =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting WebListener on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder()
                                .UseKestrel(
                                    options =>
                                    {
                                        options.NoDelay = true;
                                        options.UseConnectionLogging();
                                    })
                                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                }))
            ,
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "HttpsEndpoint", url =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting WebListener on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder()
                                .UseKestrel(
                                    options =>
                                    {
                                        options.NoDelay = true;
                                        options.UseHttps("mycert.pfx", "this_isnt_the_password");
                                        options.UseConnectionLogging();
                                    })
                                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                }))

        };
```

There are no errors at runtime, and the service does bind to the ports, but I get connection refused when attempting to connect, with no explanation as to why.

Windows Firewall is disabled.

I know it's an issue with the code (or framework / product) because if I comment out either one of the listeners, the other works, on it's respective port.  But when both are instantiated, neither works. It appears that they are somehow interfering with each other, and I have no idea in what capacity.

I have tried switching from UseKestrel() to UseWebListener() and observed the same behavior. So this is not a Kestrel-specific issue.

I have tried letting it choose the ports by not specifying them in the Endpoint, and observed the same behavior.

In short, I'm stuck.